# get data using $.ajax in React does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'requests.php',
        data: {requestKey: "hello"}
    }).done(function(data){
        this.setState({
            items: data
        });
    }.bind(this));
 }

 render(){
     let items = this.state.items;
     console.log(items);
     return(
         <div id="tops">
         <h1 className="header">
             What's top!
             <a href="#" className="more">more!</a>
         </h1>
         {items.map(function(item){
             return(
                 <TopsItem
                     img={item.img}
                     heading={item.heading}
                     desc={item.desc}
                 />
             );
         })}
         </div>
     );
}
```

The data in state.items does not effect the components in map function.
And yet I get this error:

> items.map is not a function

`console.log(items);` works after 1sec.

At first it's empty, then it gets the data in it.

Comment: `items && items.map` will work

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a default value for your `items` so that it will work until your network request has finished.

You also need to make sure that you parse the JSON string in the response of your network request.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Class {
  state = { items: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'requests.php',
      data: {requestKey: "hello"}
    }).done(function(data){
      this.setState({
        items: JSON.parse(data)
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: still got the same error: items.map is not a function:(

Comment: @S.Mhm That's frustrating. Could you `console.log` your `data` in the response to your ajax request? It might not be an array in the response.

Comment: this is the data assigned to items: `[{"img":"0.jpg","heading":"Proj 1","desc":"some text goes here!"},{"img":"0.jpg","heading":"Proj 1","desc":"some text goes here!"},{"img":"0.jpg","heading":"Proj 1","desc":"some text goes here!"}]` :( at first items value is `[]` then it's the json above!

Comment: @S.Mhm Maybe it's a string. Have you tried parsing it in the response of the reqeust? `JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 1):

initial render needs your items array to be present in state of your component.

You should initialise items in constructor like this

```
this.state = {
    items = []
}
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean, equation inside the object won't work!

Comment: place the above code inside constructor of your component.

Comment: Unexpected token (370:12)
  368 |     super(props);
  369 |     this.state = {
> 370 |       items = []
      |             ^
  371 |     }
  372 |   }

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**
JavaScript's `map`  function works with an array, and initially `this.state.items` are undefined until it gets response from ajax request.

the component get rendered before the response comes from ajax and it throws the error

**Solution**
Here we can set the initial state value `{items:[]}`, it must be an array, so it could  execute the `map()` any without error.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Class {
   constructor(props) {
       this.state = {
           items: []
       };
   }
}
```

Comment: I've done the same. but my component does not seem to be affected by the value change of `items`. the value of the `items` changes after ajax response but nothing happenes in the component. thanks